# Vue file upload - uploading the same file consecutively

Tags: typescript, file-upload, vue.js

I'm trying to make a file upload functionality for a chat app. 
My HTML looks like: (I dont use forms)

```
 <span class="file-attach mr3">
  <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" @change="attachFile($event.target.files)" multiple>
  <i class="w-10 ml4 icon-attach"></i>
</span>
```

And my typescript file looks like:

```
 async attachFile(files) {
if (!files.length) {
  return
}
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
  this.mediaLinkDocument = {
    title: this.file.type.indexOf('image') !== -1 ? '' : this.file.name,
    type: this.file.type,
    size: this.file.size,
  }
  this.sendFile(this.file)
})

Array.from(Array(files.length).keys()).forEach((id) => {
  console.log(files[id])
  this.file = files[id]

  if (this.file.size > MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE) {
    alert('O tamanho máximo é de 20 MB')
    this.file = undefined

    return
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.file)
  files = {}
})
```

}

The upload works, but if the user uploads the same image, it don't make the @change callback and the file is not uploaded.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would using the @input event work?

Comment: I doesn't. =(.
The callback isn't call at all

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Check this pen. When I select the same file more than once, the event still fires. https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/aEQeeK?editors=1111

Comment: Hey Raimond. So I tried your pen. When I try to upload a file twice in a row, the second time nothing happen. Are you telling me that this is working for you?

Comment: I did some modification at the pen to be more visual. I added a counter to show the number of uploaded files. When you try to upload the same file twice in a row, nothing happens.

https://codepen.io/davidpn11/pen/KZbQZv?editors=1111

I know is silly but this is really bugging me =(

Comment: It's working for me. What browser? I'm in Win10/FF.

Comment: Boom - that's it. Chrome replicates what you see.

Comment: Ok, check this pen: https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/eybroW?editors=1111. I added a button to "clear" the value. This mimics what you would do when the file is done uploading. In this demo, it works in Chrome and FF both.

Comment: Thats it!
You sir, are a lifesaver.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: May I add this as an answer so I can get credit? :)

Answer (score 7):

So after some research (see comments), myself and the author of the question figured out that Chrome will not fire a change event if you select the same file twice. Firefox does. So I suggested he simply set the value of the field to an empty string after the upload event is fired. That way when he selects the same file again, it will be considered a change.

Comment: For this reason, I recommend using dynamic file input element and destroy and recreate new file element once file is chosen.

Comment: So I did with this Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome did not fire the change event on the same file. to solve this issue I do as following on vuejs

```
<input
   ref="ExcelfileUpload"
   type="file"
   multiple="false"
   id="sheets"
   @change="onchangeOpenOrderUpload"
/> 



onchangeOpenOrderUpload(e) {
    ... codes
    this.$refs.ExcelfileUpload.value = "";
}
```